# How can I run code within the current window through a task

Tags: conemu

I am trying to run a command in the current window, the command works when I type it out but not when I try to put it in a task so I think I just am not figuring out the syntax.  This is what I tried:

```
-cur_console: /k "mvn clean install"
```

What winds up happening is a new console opens and runs the command in an incorrect folder, the default folder.  The current tab is opened to the correct folder so it needs to run there.

Comment: Yeah I just missed something somewhere because I thought what I had was correct :(

Comment: ConEmu does not process `/k` switch. Docs thoroughly explain where and how you may obtain proper command line to execute your shell.

Comment: that didnt help either

Comment: so are tasks not able to run in the current console? just add more tasks to the console that it opens?

Comment: Able. Add more tasks? What?

Comment: okay, maybe a new example will help. i wanted to open a specific directory in my current console tab.  i dont want to open a new tab. i want to save the call to this. how would i do that

Comment: Learn about aliases, useful to run certain commands.